# What do cursors do internally?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures

I was optimizing a stored procedure written in cursors (DECLARE cur_name CURSOR...

The client saw this SP ran for more than a day so, my manager assigned this to me.

Upon searching, I used table variable and a while loop to iterate each record.

To my surprise, the difference between the two was huge.

Someone told me that while loop is essentially, a CURSOR.

But when I used table variable with a WHILE LOOP, it ran very very very fast.

Now, what do cursors do internally?

Comment: This post is good to know about [Internal architecture of cursors](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/33237/internal-architecture-of-cursors)

Comment: The default options for cursors in SQL Server are expensive and heavy-handed. See [this post](http://sqlperformance.com/2012/09/t-sql-queries/cursor-options). Also your `WHILE` loop was still a cursor and I guarantee you can get your cursor to operate at the same speed. See [this post](https://sqlblog.org/2012/01/26/bad-habits-to-kick-thinking-a-while-loop-isnt-a-cursor).

Comment: If you could add it to your question, it would be nice to see the code for the SP that implements the cursor, and for the one that does not.

Comment: @MaxVernon - The SP is quite hard to simplify (for example's sake)... But it was implemented as "DECLARE cur_name CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR <select statement here>

Comment: A while loop is not always exactly the same as a cursor. A cursor always accesses one row at a time whereas a sql statement within a while loop can potentially still be set based, for instance all rows where level=1 then all rows where level=2 etc.

Comment: @Steve You can do the same sort of thing inside a cursor. Maybe you could illustrate the example you are talking about at http://sqlfiddle.com and I can show you.

Comment: @AaronBertrand I will try and come up with an example, but I'm thinking of a while loop used instead of a recursive CTE. I should state that I believe that you should try to avoid both cursors and while loops.

Comment: @AaronBertrand example using while loop instead of recursive cte here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c5fd8/12/0

Comment: @Steve well, yeah, while loops vs. CTE is a completely different argument than while loops vs. cursors. This is like shoes vs. sandals or shoes vs. headbands.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Cursors *are* loops, but they can be more complex for the database engine to implement depending on the options you chose.

There are many options for cursors in TSQL that can have a significant impact on performance depending on the `SELECT` that feeds the cursor with information (see [the TSQL docs for detail](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms180169.aspx)). The options will change what locks and other resources are needed, could cause parts of the query to be rerun, and so forth. Also your inner loop may be doing things that affect the behaviour of the cursor by updating base tables it reads from in a way that makes the database engine need to do more work.

If we could see the two bits of code you are talking about we could be more specific.

By running the initial query into a table variable and looping through that you are essentially emulating a `STATIC FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY` cursor, those options remove quite a chunk of the complexity that the engine might otherwise have to worry about. Your main `SELECT` is definitely run once and in one go, and your loop is not competing with other activity on the base data while it interacts with the copy in the variable.

Of course you might also find that something within your two loops (the one using the cursor and the one without) has significantly different performance metrics if they are not written exactly the same.

Comment: I literally changed cursor to table variable. Nothing more. Also, the cursor already has a FAST_FORWARD in it. Btw, what do you mean by "they(cursors) can be more COMPLEX for the database engine to implement depending on the options you chose"...? What are those complexes?

Comment: The two *can't* be identical. You need to use `FETCH NEXT` with a cursor and can't read data that way from a table variable (unless you are using a cursor to iterate that?). The extra complexities are maintaining consistency and reducing contention with other processes. If the cursor is `STATIC` you have a snapshot of the data and it doesn't have to worry about you (or other processes) updating the data during the life of the cursor, and so forth.

Comment: Ah... I see. I designed my table variable with a ROWCNT int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY. I use it to "fetch" for the next record (select * from foo where ROWCNT = @counter).

Comment: When cursor is set to static, does that mean it will hold the result set just like a temp table would?

Comment: Essentially yes, a static cursor will spool the full resultset into tempdb and iterate if from there. That doesn't mean the data ends up on disk (for large sets it will, but that is true of table variables too).

Answer (score 3):

Your solution, although a `WHILE`loop, is essentially still a cursor in the sense that you loop over a number of records and execute one or more statements once for each record. It's not the `WHILE` loop in itself, but rather the coding pattern where you loop over rows in a table and execute a statement for each row. Typically, "traditional" programming languages are row-based - this is the main difference between SQL and, for instance, C#, VBA, etc.

Why your query performs better with table variables may depend on a number of potential factors that we can't deduct from your question.

What you want to do when you're eliminating cursor-based solutions is to turn them into *set*-based solutions. Here's a very primitive pseudo-example:

```
DECLARE @sum int, @val int;

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR SELECT val FROM table;
OPEN cur;

FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @val;
WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS=0) BEGIN;
    SET @sum=@sum+@val;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @val;
END;

CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;

SELECT @sum AS grantTotal;
```

.. is equivalent to the following set-based query:

```
SELECT SUM(val) AS grandTotal FROM table;
```

In the first query, we loop over a table, row-by-row. In the second query, the entire calculation is done with the entire table as a single "set", i.e. set-based. Obviously, most cursor-based patterns will be a lot more complex, particularly if they launch a stored procedure for each row in the cursor. There isn't a single trick for how to convert a cursor-based solution to set-based one.

Comment: Hi and thank you for the reply. Reason why I didn't turn the cursors into a set based is because inside the loop, there are many conditions and if met, it will execute another SP then pass respective parameters...